# maven-publish missing artifact to repository

Tags: kotlin, gradle, maven-2, lib, maven-publish

II'm trying to publish my lib but i'm having some problems related to its publication.

I'm using this library https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin to publish my project on maven central (oss), but, this for some reason only `-sources.jar`, `-javadoc.jar` and `.module` are being pushed to the repository, however `file-butler-0.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar` is missing :(

Does someone have any idea?

[image: image presenting the files that were published to maven repository]

build.gradle(module)

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
dependencies {
    def gson = "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    def moshi = "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.11.0"
    def moshCodeGen = "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.11.0"

    implementation(Deps.core.kotlin)
    implementation(gson)
    implementation(moshi)
    kapt(moshCodeGen)

    testImplementation(Deps.testing.truth)
    testImplementation(Deps.testing.jUnit)
    kaptTest(moshCodeGen)
}
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
}
apply plugin: "com.vanniktech.maven.publish"
```

build.gradle.kts(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", "1.4.10"))
        classpath("org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")
        classpath("com.vanniktech:gradle-maven-publish-plugin:0.13.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task<Delete>("clean") {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

ps: `publishToMavenLocal` publish the expected jar to my local repository.

Comment: Where are you trying to push? I push to Maven Central fine, I can post my settings in an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @AdamArold oss.sonatype.org

You can search for https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~othiagosouto

Comment: @AdamArold sure! I'll choose as correct answer if that works for me.

Comment: oki, i'll share.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with the official maven-publish plugin.

Comment: I was having the same issue with sonatype repository and the `maven-publish` plugin (Gradle 7). At the end, it successfully uploaded the `jar` package, but in the sonatype UI, it was showing `module` instead (however with the `maven` plugin it was not happening). Even though, the jar is still downloaded without issues.

Comment: @ThiagoSouto did you figure this out?